# extends RouteComponentProps to accept more props?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this piece of typescript code in react, it's a render props component, I'm getting error because RouteComponentProps doesn't have a prop call component.

```
class Auth extends Component<RouteComponentProps> {
  render() {
    const { component: Component, ...rest } = this.props //error: Property 'component' does not exist on type 'Readonly<RouteComponentProps<{}, StaticContext, any>> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.ts(2339)


    const isAuth = getUser()

    return (
      <Route
        {...rest}
        render={props =>
          isAuth ? (
            <Component {...props} />
          ) : (
            <Redirect
              to={{
                pathname: '/login'
              }}
            />
          )
        }
      />
    )
  }
}

export default withRouter(Auth)
```

Comment: The error message is very clear. Property 'component' does not exist on type RouteComponentProps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your own interface to handle it:

```
interface MyOwnProps {
  component: React.Component;
}

class Auth extends Component<MyOwnProps & RouteComponentProps> {
  render() {
    const { component, ...rest } = this.props;
```

This should fix the error you are encountering.